# Calculating positions along the edges of a rectangle

Tags: coordinate-system, tcl

I had the following three Tcl procedures, which calculate positions along three edges of a rectangle:

```
#---- Numbered pins at the top ---------------------------------------
# Given a list of triplets (number, name, index), place the pins for the
# signals "name<index>" along the top edge, positioned vertically at 'y'
# and horizontally at 'number' times a constant space left of 'xRight'
# (plus an arbitrary offset of 2).
proc setNumberedTopPins {xRight y pins} {
    set padWidth 95
    foreach {number name index} $pins {
        set xOffset [expr $number * $padWidth + 2]
        setPin $name [expr $xRight-$xOffset] $y Top $index
    }
}
#---- Numbered pins at the right -------------------------------------
# The same for the right edge.
proc setNumberedRightPins {x yTop pins} {
    set padWidth 95
    foreach {number name index} $pins {
        set yOffset [expr max(0, $number * $padWidth - 2.5)]
        setPin $name $x [expr $yTop-$yOffset] Right $index
    }
}
#---- Numbered pins at the bottom ------------------------------------
# The same for the bottom edge.
proc setNumberedBottomPins {xRight y pins} {
    set padWidth 95
    foreach {number name index} $pins {
        set xOffset [expr $number * $padWidth + 2]
        setPin $name [expr $xRight-$xOffset] $y Bottom $index
    }
}
```

Since the code for each of the procedures is almost identical, I decided to write a single generalized procedure and three specializations of it.

I had some difficulties with generalizing the fact that the `offset` is sometimes applied to the second (`x`) and sometimes to the third (`y`) argument of `setPin`. I wanted to make sure that this decision is only taken once, outside the `foreach` loop.

Here is the solution I came up with:

```
#---- Numbered pins at the top ---------------------------------------
proc setNumberedTopPins {xRight y pins} {
    setNumberedPins Top 2 $xRight $y $pins
}
#---- Numbered pins at the right -------------------------------------
proc setNumberedRightPins {x yTop pins} {
    setNumberedPins Right -2.5 $x $yTop $pins
}
#---- Numbered pins at the bottom ------------------------------------
proc setNumberedBottomPins {xRight y pins} {
    setNumberedPins Bottom 2 $xRight $y $pins
}
#---- Generic numbered pins ------------------------------------------
proc setNumberedPins {side offsetPin0 x y pins} {
    set padWidth 95
    switch $side {
        Top - Bottom {set coords {list [expr $x-$offset] $y}}
        Right {set coords {list $x [expr $y-$offset]}}
    }
    foreach {number name index} $pins {
        set offset [expr max(0, $number * $padWidth + $offsetPin0)]
        setPin $name {*}[eval $coords] $side $index
    }
}
```

I'm not an experienced Tcl programmer and I wonder if there is a better way to solve this. Particularly, there is still some amount of code duplication left (almost identical definition of auxiliary variable `coords` inside `switch`) and I would like to eliminate that (while keeping the code reasonably readable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that since only 2 of the procs are close enough to identical, just "combine" those:

```
set padWidth 95

proc setNumberedRightPins {x yTop pins} {
    foreach {number name index} $pins {
        set yOffset [expr {max(0, $number * $::padWidth - 2.5)}]
        setPin $name $x [expr {$yTop-$yOffset}] Right $index
    }
}

proc setNumberedTopPins {args} {
    setNumberedTopOrBottomPins {*}$args Top
}

proc setNumberedBottomPins {args} {
    setNumberedTopOrBottomPins {*}$args Bottom
}

proc setNumberedTopOrBottomPins {xRight y pins side} {
    foreach {number name index} $pins {
        set xOffset [expr {$number * $::padWidth + 2}]
        setPin $name [expr {$xRight-$xOffset}] $y $side $index
    }
}
```

Notes:

- always [brace your expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17451671/7552), gain a big performance boost
- constants can live in the global namespace, and you access them with a fully qualified variable name

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! Things I will take from it: using the magic `args` argument; bracing the `expr`essions (it's always good to have good habits, although it will not make a noticable speed difference in this case). I did know about referring to global variables with `::`, but I wanted to keep the "knowledge" of the `padWidth` within the function. And I would rather like to generalize more, not less, so I kept the single `setNumberedPins` procedure.

Answer (score 0):

After learning about arrays [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29844439/4621513), I attempted to put them to use and now have found a version of the `setNumberedPins` procedure that I am happy with.

The main difference is that instead of dynamically assigning one of two possible (and very similar, thereby repeating myself) pieces of code to a variable inside `switch`, which is then evaluated later, I only decide which of the coordinates `x` or `y` is the `const`ant one and which is the `var`iable one and then using these for indexing the array.

I also put braces around the `expr` argument(s), [as suggested by glenn jackman](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/87780/67888).

```
proc setNumberedPins {side offsetPin0 x y pins} {
    set padWidth 95
    switch $side {
        Top - Bottom {lassign {x y} var const}
        Right        {lassign {x y} const var}
    }
    set coords($const) [set $const]
    foreach {number name index} $pins {
        set offset [expr {max(0, $number * $padWidth + $offsetPin0)}]
        set coords($var) [expr {[set $var] - $offset}]
        setPin $name $coords(x) $coords(y) $side $index
    }
}
```

(Before posting the code here, I thought `const` and `var` had no special meaning in Tcl, but now I am surprised that they are syntax highlighted...)